# Drop records from dataset in a for loop with certain conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, recommendation-engine

I have a dataset with say song, song id, user, listen counts. And I want to remove that user from the dataset while working on a recommendation system. For this I have to filter the data for each user so that recommendation system works perfectly. Please suggest any other smart way

```
  user_id = users[x]
    song_df_x = song_df[song_df['user_id'] != 'user_id']
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `song_df['user_id'] != user_id` (the variable not the string name of the variable)?

Answer (score 0):

```
song_df_x = song_df[~song_df['user_id'].isin(users)]
```